# using \lstinline withtin glossaries - sorting problem

Tags: listings, glossaries, sorting

I seem to have a sorting problem using glossaries... I am not quite sure what exactly the problem is, but I cant get rid of it

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[acronym, symbols, nomain, toc, sanitizesort]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries 
\newglossary*{glsentry}{Glossary}
     \newglossaryentry{hi}{         
             type=glsentry, 
             name={\lstinline|high impedance|}, 
             description={describes a logical signal state which is not to be recognized as \lstinline|high| or \lstinline|low|}}
     \newglossaryentry{an}{         
             type=glsentry, 
             name={another}, 
             description={another entry}}

\begin{document}    
\printnoidxglossary[type = glsentry]        
\section{test}  
\gls{hi} \\     
\gls{an}     
\end{document}
```

I could try somethings like `sort=def`, `sort=word` etc. but the 'name' auf the entry, does not occur at the right place within the glossary...if I use `sort=use` or `sort=last` it is the last entry displayed, but the name does not come up at all...

I am probably doing something wrong and its surely nothing, but I have no more ideas. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I noticed, that my minimal example is using bold `itemlabels` within the glossary, but my actual project does not...this is why I added an extra example, with all the related options (as far as I can assume)...but this does contain the bold "high impedance" within the glossary as well, my project does not.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-mode = false,
    detect-family=true,
    mode=math,
    %               output-decimal-marker={,},
    binary-units=true,
    group-separator={\,},group-minimum-digits=3%
}

\usepackage[acronym, symbols, nomain, toc, sanitizesort, style=index]{glossaries}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % essential for customized symbol glossary
\usepackage{tabu}   % essential for customized symbol glossary
\glsnoexpandfields
    % create customized symbols
    \newglossarystyle{symblongtabu}{
        \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
            \begin{longtabu}spread 0pt[l]{lll<{\strut}l}
            }{
        \end{longtabu}}
        \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
        \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
        \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
            \toprule
            \bfseries Formelzeichen & \bfseries Beschreibung &
            \bfseries Einheit & \bfseries Seite(n)
            \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead
            \bottomrule\endfoot}
        \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
            \glsentryitem{##1}
            % Entry number if required
            \glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}} &
            \glossentrydesc{##1} &
            \glsentryuseri{##1} &
            ##2\tabularnewline}}


\makenoidxglossaries

    % symbol entries without description
\newcommand*{\nsymbol}[4]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{
        type=symbols,
        name={#2},
        description={\nopostdesc},
        symbol={\ensuremath{#3}}, 
        %               user1={#4}, 
        user1={$\si{#4}$}, 
        sort={#1}}}
\newcommand*{\nsymbold}[5]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{
        type=symbols,
        name={#2},
        description={#5},
        symbol={\ensuremath{#3}}, 
        %               user1={#4}, 
        user1={$\si{#4}$}, 
        sort={#1}}}
\defglsentryfmt[symbols]{\ifmmode
    \glssymbol{\glslabel}
    \else
    \glsgenentryfmt~\glsentrysymbol{\glslabel}
    \fi}

    \nsymbold{i}{current}{i_1}{\ampere}{current of line 1}

    \newacronym{ac}{AC}{Accounting Current}

\newglossary*{glsentry}{Glossary}
    \newglossaryentry{hi}{
        type=glsentry, name={\lstinline|high impedance|}, description={describes an signal state which is not to be recognized as \lstinline|high| or \lstinline|low|}}
    \newglossaryentry{hi2}{
        type=glsentry, name={high impedance}, description=describes an signal state which is not to be recognized as high or low}
    \newglossaryentry{an}{
        type=glsentry, name={another}, description={another entry}}


\begin{document}


\printnoidxglossary[type = acronym, title = {glos1}]
\printnoidxglossary[type = glsentry, style=index]

\printnoidxglossary[type = symbols, style = symblongtabu, title = {glos2}]

    \newpage

    \section{test}
    \gls{hi}\\
    \gls{i}\\
    \gls{ac}


\end{document}
```

Maybe someone got some time to waste and is able to assume what I am using wrong...

Comment: I realize an MWE can leave out stuff, in the name of simplicity, relative to your actual application. but why do you wish to use `\lstinline` at all.  What is it doing for you in this context?

Comment: not quite sure what MWE means, but thanks for the respond.
Well I need to explain such things as high impedance or a few programming commands which I would like to display with `\lstinline`

Comment: I mean it could be possible to create a command glossary for instants...thats something to use `\lstinline` for sure (or any other code formatting package

Comment: You glossary style doesn't use `\glossentryname` within `\glossentry` so the name's not going to show. You might be better off posting that as a follow-up question.

Comment: well if you are talking about the `\newglossaryentrystyle{symblongtabu}` that is alright...the symbol glossary is as I want it to be. 
The 'bold-`itemlabel`' issue is still with the glossary entry of "high impedance" - As I understand it is using another style than the symbol glossary...but alright
PS: It is difficult to explain, because the issue does NOT occur with the given minimal example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to understand what `\printnoidxglossary` is trying to do. With the default `style=list`, it's using the `description` environment and putting the `name` inside the optional argument of `\item`. So test this out:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\test}{\lstinline|high impedance|}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[\test] test.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: test.]

The item label is lost, which means the same is going to happen with `glossaries` if you use this style. (I suspect this may have something to do with `\lstinline`'s verbatim-like qualities.)

The `index` style is a reasonable approximation, so use `style=index`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[acronym, symbols, nomain, toc, sanitizesort,style=index]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries 
\newglossary*{glsentry}{Glossary}
     \newglossaryentry{hi}{         
             type=glsentry, 
             name={\lstinline|high impedance|}, 
             description={describes a logical signal state which is not to be recognized as \lstinline|high| or \lstinline|low|}}
     \newglossaryentry{an}{         
             type=glsentry, 
             name={another}, 
             description={another entry}}

\begin{document}    
\printnoidxglossary[type = glsentry]        
\section{test}  
\gls{hi} \\     
\gls{an}     
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

"high impedance" comes before "another" because the sort values are `\lstinline|high impedance|` and `another`. The first value starts with `\` and the second starts with `a`. You're using `\makenoidxglossaries` which performs an ASCII sort and the character code for `\` is less than the character code for `a`. If you want to change this ordering, you need to specify the `sort` value:

```
\newglossaryentry{hi}{
     type=glsentry,
     name={\lstinline|high impedance|},
     sort={high impedance},
     description={describes a logical signal state which is not to be   
     recognized as \lstinline|high| or \lstinline|low|}}
```

Comment: Well thank you very much for this helpfull explanation and solution. I cant extract those kind of information out of the package documentations...but mybe this just takes some experience.
However, I still dont understand, why, depending on the `sort`-option the `itemlabel` is missing at all (not the description) or is shifted into another 'item', BUT fully formatted. But thats not that important I'd say...

Comment: @Djiwahwah It's experience :-) I rather regret making the `list` style the default as it turns out there are so many situations where it can go wrong. (Not to mention the number of classes and packages that alter the `description` environment.) The `index` style would've been much better as the default, but I can't change it now. The `\makenoidxglossaries` method is quite problematic. I recommend `\makeglossaries` with the `automake` package option if you can't integrate the external tools.

Comment: yeah...I am kinda struggle on how to use those "extra programs" (xindy, cli)...I guess it is not that hard...but for now I stick with option 1 - Ill switch probably for future thesis.
Anyway, I noticed that within my minimal example the `itemlabel` is bold, which it is supposed to do, but within my real project it is not. I will update an minimal example with all the other stuff which might effect glossarie...